# Unable to create table in snowflake from databricks for kafka topic

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

I am connecting a kafka topic, applying some transformation on dataframe and writing that data in snowflake with help of databricks. If table is present, it is successfully writing the data. However, if it is not present, it is giving me an error:

```
 net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error:
Object 'new_table_name' does not exist or not authorized.
```

This is the code I am using:

```
def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id): 
    df.write.format("snowflake").options(**sfOptions).option("dbtable", "new_table_name").mode('append').save()

query = my_df.writeStream.foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function).trigger(processingTime='30 seconds').start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

Note : With the same user I can create a new table manually in snowflake.

Comment: Since you're using the **append** mode that means the table must exist. If you're using the Spark connector for this, you could probably run a **preactions** to create the table if it doesn't exists, which would only create the table if it's not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the mode is changed to "Overwrite", it is creating table but old data of previous batch job was getting deleted.

preactions was creating table but was not suitable for current scenario. As it is creating for each batch and thus failing.

So, I used following part to create table if it doesn't exist.

```
sf_utils = sc._jvm.net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils
sf_utils.runQuery(sfOptions,"create table if not exists {table_name} like existing_table".format(table_name=db_table))
```